# ffmpeg: How to speed up (and keep only) a specified portion of an input video

Tags: ffmpeg, trim, timelapse

In my input video is a 48 second range that I wish to speed up. I wish to save only that sped up portion to a new video.

Solution:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:48 -i input.mp4 -an -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=1080:-1, setpts=PTS/10.0" "output.mp4"
```

Comment: Does the file have an audio stream (it may be silent) ?

Comment: It may be silent.   (-an).  I'll update the description--thanks!

Comment: Paste the readout of `ffmpeg -i input.mp4`

Comment: I've added the '-i' results into the original post

Comment: There is an audio stream in the input. Add -report and rerun the command and share report.

Comment: You solved it!  I claimed in my post that I'd included "-an" and yet in subsequent runs, I dropped it without knowing it... When I add "-an" back into the command, all is fine.

Comment: @shrimpwidget You can add an answer to your question.